# Include blank and default for collection_select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I would like to have a "select an option" option in my dropdown on my rails application.

I am using the `collection_select` helper tag and it looks something like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:country, :id, Country.order('name ASC'), :id,:name, {},{:class => "input-xlarge"}) %>
```

I want the default option of the drop-down to be "Select a country".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `include_blank` option:

```
<%= collection_select(:country, :id, Country.order('name ASC'),
      :id, :name, 
      { include_blank: 'Select a country' }, 
      { :class => "input-xlarge" }) %>
```

See the [official documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)