# Undefined method 'unshift'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a new Rails app with Rails 6 and I want to do something like this:

```
@items = Item.all.unshift Item.new(id: 0, name: '-- Kein Item --')
```

But I get the error "undefined method `unshift' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Item id: 1, name: "Item 1", created_at: "2021-03-13 11:09:34.284978000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-03-13 11:09:34.284978000 +0000">]>"

In another Rails app I can do it, but that app is running under Rails 4.

I want to add this "empty" record so that model project hast not everytime an item and because I have somewhere Project.item.name it won't give an nil error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `unshift` works on arrays, which `Item.all` is not. You can do `Item.all.to_a << Item.new...` if you want but it very much seems to me you're solving the wrong problem by doing that.

Comment: The thing is that I want to have a blank in collection_select where this empty option has a value with '0', so how can I do that?

Comment: You can make it work like this sure, or you can look into the `include_blank` option. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22230351/308731